# Java generics trouble

Tags: java, generics

I'm about to give up on that snippet: I don't grok Java generics... I'm trying to return the value of an enum when getting a System property with that enum name, as in:

```
enum E { A, B }
...
E mode = GetEnumProperty("mode", E.A);
```

where GetEnumProperty is:

```
static <T> T GetEnumProperty(String propName, T extends Enum<T> defaultValue)
{
    if (System.getProperty(propName) != null) {
        return Enum.valueOf(defaultValue.getClass(), System.getProperty(propName));
    } else {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to be a bit more specific about what you're asking here.

Comment: Never give up! Generics need brain-juice but it's doable :)

Comment: Please add more information, you have not been very clear about your problem.

Comment: No question update after 10 minutes = vote to close. Sorry.

Comment: No time to go to the restroom, Rob?

Comment: :) Nope. Seriously, though, 10 minutes is a *long* time to SO. If you update your question to ask something more than "help?", you've probably got my reopen vote, though.

Comment: Well, I was hoping the code was a more or less clear specification of what I'm trying to do: get a System property value to set the value of an enum. Is that clearer?

Comment: OK Rob, I'll know for later. I thought it was slower.

Comment: High volume tags get a lot of visibility. It's not uncommon to have several answers within the first minute. It's advisable to stick around after asking in case people need clarification. If you don't, people will have moved onto someone else's question and you won't get the best answers possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3797/discussion-between-frank-and-rob-hruska)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you want is this:

```java
public class GenericEnum {
    static <T extends  Enum<T>> T GetEnumProperty(String propName, T defaultValue)
    {
        if (System.getProperty(propName) != null) {
            return (T)Enum.valueOf(defaultValue.getClass(), System.getProperty(propName));
        } else {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }
```

Notice the change in how generic type T is specified in the method declaration.  You need to declare that the type T extends Enum before you use it in the parameter list.

Also note the cast (T) in the first return statement.

Comment: It works great, albeit with an "unchecked cast" warning...

Answer (score 0):

You need some Generics background- this is basic generics here.

Dense, but helpful white-paper - http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Sigh. Shhhhh... I'm trying to help with generic feedback!

Comment: Yeah, well, I come from C++, and I read the generics tutorial twice, and I still think Java generics totally suck.

Comment: Java generics 99% suck, not totally - let's be precise please.

Comment: Sure, I'll grant you that :-)